# Developing Angular4 in VS2017 without packaging JS files into a single file

Tags: angular, webpack, asp.net-core

We started a new project using the dotnet template for Angular 4 which uses ASP.NET Core and JavascriptServices as described [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/02/14/building-single-page-applications-on-asp-net-core-with-javascriptservices/). We used `dotnet new angular` to generate the project.

We noticed that when running the project all the TS files get packaged into a single JS file *main-client.js*, this is done through webpack.

How would we need to change the webpack config file so that it keeps the JS files separate, one per TS file and load them individually on the browser?

From my experience this would simplify debugging in the browser and development overall. I understand there are source map files that allow us to debug the TS files, but I would prefer to debug the JS files and disable source mapping on the browser devtools.

Comment: Soooooo you prefer having 200 different script files? Because that's pretty easy to get up to those numbers in a Angular app. Can you imagine every time you reload requesting 200 files?

Comment: @FabioAntunes I should have made it clear this would be for local development only. We have projects with those numbers of files with no issues.